# Providing local file to swagger ui through Docker

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui

I have read on https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/ that it is possible to host a local file (swagger.json) on swagger ui through docker by writing 
`docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v /bar:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

since my swagger.json file is located at C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final I have written this as

```
docker run -p 8086:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/mnt/swagger.json -v C:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final:/mnt swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

However I still get the default petstore example and not my own swagger.json when looking at http://127.0.0.1:8086/.

I have tried to change whats written in the explore bar to be different than the default value (https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) to swagger.json which gives a not found on the website itself and on the docker host

```
[error] 26#26: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /swagger.json HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8090", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8090/"
```

and C:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/swagger.json which gives the error on the website'

```
Fetch errorFailed to fetch C:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/swagger.json
Fetch errorPossible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (file://) does not match the page (http://127.0.0.1:8086). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.
```

Any Ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, I was having same problem.
Key to understand is that `SWAGGER_JSON`must point to a path **inside of the container** and not on your local file system. Essentially, what you are doing is: first mount the folder where you have your `swagger.json`locally and then swagger-ui uses the `SWAGGER_JSON` environmental variable to find it.

```sh
docker run \
    --name swagger \
    --rm \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -e SWAGGER_JSON=/bar/swagger.json \
    -v /c/my/local/path/to/swagger/file:/bar \
    swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Answer (score -1):

For people facing this issue in mac, its a permission problem. By default after Catalina, docker doesn't have permission to allow its images to read local files in your system. Once its given it worked for me and it took my local swagger json file.

To grant privileges now, go to System preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders, and add Docker for Mac and your shared directory.

[image]